# Redefining JDK Bootstrap classes

Tags: bytecode, javaagents, byte-buddy

Is it possible to redefine Bootstrap classes using Java agent during runtime?
To be more specific, I want to redefine some classes in `java.io` package **during runtime** after they have been loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible using a Javaagent that is capable of redefining classes since many classes in `java.io` will already be loaded once your agent is activated. To do so, you have to create a jar file with a `premain` method that declares the `Can-Redefine-Classes` or `Can-Retransform-Classes` property.

Doing so, you can register a `ClassFileTransformer` with retransformation capabilities and retransform the classes you require to change. Note that this does not allow you to change the class file layout by for example adding fields or methods.

You can use a library such as ByteBuddy that offers a standard way of retransforming classes [using its `AgentBuilder` to simplify the process](https://www.sitepoint.com/fixing-bugs-in-running-java-code-with-dynamic-attach/). Note that you have to define an ignore matcher that does not exclude all bootstrap classes what is the default to accomplish this.

Comment: Thanks Rafael. Is there any way to inject a field into java.lang.Runnable using that mechanism? If I understood correctly, we can't change the class layout dynamically.

Comment: No, you cannot add a field to this class which will always be loaded prior to your agent.

Comment: Adding a field to an *interface* would be of limited use anyway, as only static constants are allowed in an interface.